# CURL Rest API with Base64 encoded Key

Tags: json, rest, curl

I am trying to set up a integration with a REST API, that requires a Base64 encoded key to authenticate, and I cannot seem to get it to work.

The API only returns:

```
<Code>-4</Code><Message>Not Authenticated</Message>
"Please provide a valid username and password"
```

**My request looks like this:**

```
curl -i 
-H 'application/json'
-X GET 
-H 'basic :Base64EncodedKey' 
http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/filter/all
```

No username should be supplied, thats why I use : before the key.

Can someone please try to help me? I am not a developer, I am just in charge of generating code examples.

/Max

Comment: `curl -i -XGET --user username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://...."` where you should replace username and password with its actual values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is `Authorization: Basic Base64EncodedKey`. You are missing the Authorization portion in your header.

```
-H 'Authorization: Basic Base64EncodedKey'
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A little trick of generate your base64 encode:

```
echo -n admin:123456 | base64
YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2
```

Then use it like this:

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2" http://nexus.xxxxcloud.com/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content
```